# $(...).DataTable is not a function error when trying to view datatables

Tags: jquery, database, datatables

I'm trying to load the contents of my database using datatables but I'm getting this error $(...).DataTable is not a function - I have my scripts in this order:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<scripts src="~/plugins-site/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></scripts>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<link href="~/lib/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
```

Another reason I think this might be wrong is the contents of the page are being loaded from layout page and the page I am on now. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: One very common cause is loading another version of jQuery.js further down the page. The second one will wipe out the first and any plugins assigned to the first

Comment: If you still need a sanity-check of the resources you are using, you can visit the official [downloads page](https://datatables.net/download/index).